# Gitorious can not connect to Active Directory (authentication.yml)

Tags: git, authentication, active-directory, centos-6, github

I have set up Gitorious. With the local database, everything worked fine.
All my log and configurationfiles are included.
The problem is when I want to visit gitorious.localdomain when I have configured Gitorious to authenticate using the active directory. I receive a 502 Bad Gateway error from nginx.

Update: If I rename or delete the authentication.yml file. I don't get an error and I can connect with the local database. So I think the error must be inside the authentication.yml, but I'm still not able to solve it.

This is my authentication.yml

```
production:
disable_default: true
methods:
    - adapter: Gitorious::Authentication::LDAPAuthentication
    host: activedirectory.lab

    # Override the default port (389)
    #port: 1999

    # The base DN to search
    #base_dn: DC=domain,DC=local

    # The base DN when searching for groups (for authorization)
    # If unspecified, base_dn is used
    group_search_dn: OU=ouname,dc=domainname,dc=local

    # What LDAP attribute to use for user authentication. Default is CN
    # login_attribute: uid  

    # How to build a user's DN. Default: $LOGIN_ATTRIBUTE={},$BASE_DN,
    # e.g. CN=chris,DC=gitorious,DC=org
    distinguished_name_template: "{}@thename.local"

    bind_user:
    username: user@thename.local
    password: Password

    # When using LDAP authorization: which attribute in a user
    # record specifies groups a user is member of
    # This will depend on your schema/LDAP server implementation
    # but in 9/10 cases, it will be memberof
    membership_attribute_name: memberof

    # When using LDAP authorization: which attribute in a group
    # record specifies users that are member of the group
    # This will depend on your  LDAP schema, but will usually be
    # member or uniquemember
    members_attribute_name: member
```

In the file gitorious.yml. I have uncommented the next rule:

> use_ldap_authorization: true

The output of "/var/log/nginx/access.log":

> 10.203.40.148 - - [08/Apr/2013:12:12:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31" "-"
>       10.203.40.148 - - [08/Apr/2013:12:12:56 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31" "-"

the output of "/var/log/nginx/error.log"

> 2013/04/08 12:12:56 [error] 1571#0: *9 connect() to u.n.i.x.:///var/www/gitorious/app/tmp/pids/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.203.40.148, server: gitorious.localdomain, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://u.n.i.x.:///var/www/gitorious/app/tmp/pids/unicorn.sock:/", host: "10.203.40.150"
>       2013/04/08 12:12:56 [error] 1571#0: *9 connect() to u.n.i.x.:///var/www/gitorious/app/tmp/pids/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.203.40.148, server: gitorious.localdomain, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://u.n.i.x.:///var/www/gitorious/app/tmp/pids/unicorn.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "10.203.40.150"

the output of "bundle exec rails c RAILS_ENV=production script/test_ldap_connection username password"

> [root@Gitorious app]# 
>         exists
>         exists  app/controllers
>         exists  app/helpers
>         exists  app/models
>         exists  app/views/layouts
>         exists  config/environments
>         exists  config/initializers
>         exists  config/locales
>         exists  db
>         exists  doc
>         exists  lib
>         exists  lib/tasks
>         exists  log
>         exists  public/images
>         exists  public/javascripts
>         exists  public/stylesheets
>         exists  script/performance
>         exists  test/fixtures
>         exists  test/functional
>         exists  test/integration
>         exists  test/performance
>         exists  test/unit
>         exists  vendor
>         exists  vendor/plugins
>         exists  tmp/sessions
>         exists  tmp/sockets
>         exists  tmp/cache
>         exists  tmp/pids
>       identical  Rakefile
>       identical  README
>       identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
>       identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
>       identical  config/database.yml
>       identical  config/routes.rb
>       identical  config/locales/en.yml
>       identical  db/seeds.rb
>       identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
>       identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
>       identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
>       identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
>       overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y
>          force  config/initializers/session_store.rb
>       overwrite config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb? (enter "h" for help)     [Ynaqdh] y
>          force  config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb
>       identical  config/environment.rb
>       identical  config/boot.rb
>       identical  config/environments/production.rb
>       identical  config/environments/development.rb
>       identical  config/environments/test.rb
>       identical  script/about
>       identical  script/console
>       identical  script/dbconsole
>       identical  script/destroy
>       identical  script/generate
>       identical  script/runner
>       identical  script/server
>       identical  script/plugin
>       identical  script/performance/benchmarker
>       identical  script/performance/profiler
>       identical  test/test_helper.rb
>       identical  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
>       identical  public/404.html
>       identical  public/422.html
>       identical  public/500.html
>       identical  public/index.html
>       identical  public/favicon.ico
>       identical  public/robots.txt
>       identical  public/images/rails.png
>       identical  public/javascripts/prototype.js
>       identical  public/javascripts/effects.js
>       identical  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
>       identical  public/javascripts/controls.js
>       identical  public/javascripts/application.js
>       identical  doc/README_FOR_APP
>       identical  log/server.log
>       identical  log/production.log
>       identical  log/development.log
>       identical  log/test.log

The output of log/production.log

> [root@Gitorious app]# tail log/production.log
>       # Logfile created on Mon Apr 08 11:35:56 +0200 2013[root@Gitorious app]#

Answer (score 0):

In authentication.yml, your base_dn line is commented out, have you tried with this set and uncommented?

After uncommenting that, try run "RAILS_ENV=production script/test_ldap_connection username password" from the app directory.